# Make Dialog box take up only as much space as needed in terms of height?

Tags: html, css

My CSS is :

```
#login, #addItemContainer, #searchDialog, #createBill, #createExpense, #editItemContainer, #reloadBill {

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;

    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255,170,107,0.8);
    text-align: center;
}

#addItemContainer, #editItemContainer {
    width: 405px;
    height: 700px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

This leads to a satisfactory result of :

[image: Dialog box height correct]

But this won't work when a validation message is dynamically generated. The height also needs to increase dynamically. Setting `height: auto` leads to it taking up the entire height of the browser.

[image]

Even applying `min-width: 700px` leads to above. What should I do?

Note that I have to use position absolute and the next few lines to ensure that the dialog box is centered both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: `height: auto` takes whole screen probably because its parent element - for example body has `height:100%`

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou Any suggestions on how I can get the minimum height to 700px while still expanding based on content?

Comment: normally just do not use `height` attribute at all, then it would expand with its contents - but then again it depends if css rules in parent elements do not affect this. Instead of using 700px, just use padding and/or margin to expand the height, fixed heights are mostly never a good idea when you want something dynamic